# PID Compensation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, controls

Im trying to design a PID compensator with Matlab.
I'm doing the following:

My plant has this transfer function:

```
plant 


       ( 0.0195 s - 6.5  )/ (1.74e-06 s^2 - 0.003 s - 1)
```

So, using the PID tune function, specifying the desired crossover frequency:

```
>> [info,pid_c] = pidtune(plant,'PID',(2E6/6)*2*pi)

info =


  Kp + Ki * 1/s


  with Kp = 162, Ki = 1.96e+08

Continuous-time PI controller in parallel form.


pid_c =

                Stable: 1
    CrossoverFrequency: 2.0944e+06
           PhaseMargin: 60.0000
```

But, when I close the loop and analyse the poles of the system I see that there's a pole in the right semi-plane:

```
>> pid_c = 162 + 1.96E8/s

pid_c =

(  162 s + 1.96e08 ) /  s

Continuous-time transfer function.

>> sys=feedback(plant*pid_c,1)

sys =

         (3.159 s^2 + 3.821e06 s - 1.274e09 )/ ( 1.74e-06 s^3 + 3.156 s^2 + 3.821e06 s - 1.274e09)

Continuous-time transfer function.

>> pole(sys)

ans =

   1.0e+06 *

  -0.9071 + 1.1721i

  -0.9071 - 1.1721i

   0.0003 <==== RSP pole
```

My intuition says I should get away with this pole by adding a (s+0.0003) to the numerator of the PID:

```
>> pid_c=pid_c*(s+0.0003)

pid_c =

(  162 s^2 + 1.96e08 s + 5.88e04 )/  s
```

But it doesnt work at all, and the tranfer function of my closed-loop goes like that:

```
sys =

  (3.159 s^3 + 3.821e06 s^2 - 1.274e09 s - 3.822e05) /  (3.159 s^3 + 3.821e06 s^2 - 1.274e09 s - 3.822e05)
```

and off course thats wrong.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Whilst your question is very hard to decipher because you have neglected to format it, I don't actually see you asking a question that we can answer...

Comment: I have reformatted the question so that it's slightly easier to decipher what's going on. It looks like you are overwriting the `pid_c` controller generated by `pid_tune`. Don't do that. You have also neglected the fact that the pole isn't at `0.0003`, but at `0.0003 * 1e6`.

Comment: You might also want to use `format long g` to get more significant digits for the location of the RHP pole. Also use `minreal` when computing the closed-loop transfer function, you have some really large numbers combined with really small ones, not a good combination.

Comment: BTW, the correct call to `pidtune` is `[pid_c,info] = pidtune(...)`, then your controller is in `pid_c`, ready to be used. No need to obverwrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are not calling `pidtune` correctly. The first variable returned is the controller, the second the information about closed-loop stability, not the other way round. From the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/pidtune.html):

> `[C,info] = pidtune(...)` returns the data structure `info`, which
>   contains information about closed-loop stability, the selected
>   open-loop gain crossover frequency, and the actual phase margin.

So I would change the code to:

```
[pid_c,info] = pidtune(plant,'PID',(2E6/6)*2*pi);
sys=minreal(feedback(pid_c*plant,1));
pole(sys)
```

The second error you make is that the pole isn't at `0.0003`, but at `0.0003 * 1e6`. If you are going to rely on what is displayed on the screen, you should at least use `format long g` to have more significant digits.

Also, note that I have used `minreal` to compute a minimum realisation of the closed-loop transfer function, as you seem to be having a mix of very large and very small number, not a good combination.

Comment: thanks a lot ! the minreal function helped me out. and yes, i was misleaded by the wrong format of pidtune and by the 1E6 coefficient.

Comment: No problem. If the answer has helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers